# Angular: Custom validation with parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to implement a verify password validation with Angular 6 using Reactive Form but I can't get the best way to do it, below an example that works with "1234" but I would like to pass the value of the password control instead. 
I tried with ValidatePWD(this) but doesn't work either.

```
 //component.ts
 import { ValidatePWD } from './compare.validator';

 this.form = this._fb.group({
                  'user': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],                       
                  'password': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
                  'verifypassword': ['', [Validators.required, ValidatePWD]],

 });


//compare.validator.ts
import { AbstractControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
export function ValidatePWD(control: AbstractControl ) {    
  if (control.value != "1234") {
    return { validPWD: true };
  }
  return null;
}


<div class="form-group">
      <label>Password: {{model.password}}</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="model.password" [formControl]="password" class="form-control" type="password">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
     <label >Verify Password</label>
     <input[(ngModel)]="model.verifypassword" [formControl]="verifypassword"  class="form-control" type="password">
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Option 1 - Validate the `password` and `verifyPassword` through `FormGroup`,

Here is simple sample code for confirm password validation where you need to pass the validator to `FormGroup` which contains both the contols `password` and `confirmPassword`.

```
  this.form = this._fb.group({
              'user': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],                       
              'password': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
              'verifypassword': ['', [Validators.required]],

  }, { validator: this.passwordMatchValidator });

  passwordMatchValidator(g: FormGroup) {
    return g.get('password').value === g.get('verifypassword').value
       ? null : {'mismatch': true};
  }
```

### html

```
<div *ngIf="form.invalid && form.errors['mismatch']">Password did not match</div>
```

Sample example is here -https://stackblitz.com/edit/confirm-password-q3ngps

> Option 2 - Use a function to match the password.

#### password-validator.ts

```
export class PasswordValidation {

    static MatchPassword(AC: AbstractControl) {
        let password = AC.get('password').value;
        if(AC.get('confirmPassword').touched || AC.get('confirmPassword').dirty) {
            let verifyPassword = AC.get('confirmPassword').value;

            if(password != verifyPassword) {
                AC.get('confirmPassword').setErrors( {MatchPassword: true} )
            } else {
                return null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Component ts

```
this.form = this._fb.group({
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
    }, {
      validator: PasswordValidation.MatchPassword
    });
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-password-confirm-pnnd4t

Comment: it works but only when i press the submit button, i wuold like to check the validation  as soon as the user touch the verifypassword field

Comment: I think you had put the condition in html when to show the error. Share your html.

Comment: just because i am using the css ng-valid,  ng-invalid, you know  the validation password if is differents must be invalid ...after that if is invalid i can add a message

Comment: you can capture the error in `FormGroup` instead of `FormControl` of verify password itself. Updated the answer.

Comment: Please have a look to the question there is an image that show you that the field is valid even if there is a text that says 'password doesn't match'  and this is not the effect that i am looking for. btw  thank you so much for your help

Comment: Added the option 2 in answer, that should solve your issue.